# How to bypass bash functions called `command`, `builtin` and `unset`?

Tags: shell, function, shell-builtin

I am aware that aliases can be bypassed by quoting the command itself.

However, it seems that if builtin commands are "shadowed" by functions with the same names, there is no way to execute the underlying builtin command except...by using a builtin command.  If you can get to it.

To quote the bash man page (at `LESS='+/^COMMAND EXECUTION' man bash`):

```
COMMAND EXECUTION
       After a command has been split into words, if it results  in  a  simple
       command  and  an  optional list of arguments, the following actions are
       taken.

       If the command name contains no slashes, the shell attempts  to  locate
       it.   If  there  exists a shell function by that name, that function is
       invoked as described above in FUNCTIONS.  If the name does not match  a
       function,  the shell searches for it in the list of shell builtins.  If
       a match is found, that builtin is invoked.
```

---

So, is it possible to recover from the following, without starting a new shell?

```
unset() { printf 'Haha, nice try!\n%s\n' "$*";}
builtin() { printf 'Haha, nice try!\n%s\n' "$*";}
command() { printf 'Haha, nice try!\n%s\n' "$*";}
```

I didn't even add `readonly -f unset builtin command`.  If it *is* possible to recover from the above, consider this a bonus question: can you still recover if all three functions are marked readonly?

---

I came up with this question in Bash, but I'm interested in its applicability to other shells as well.

Comment: `set -o posix`, then you have `unset` is *builtin* instead of your fucntion, then `unset builtin` `unset command`.

Comment: @cuonglm, that looks like an answer.

Comment: @cuonglm I do hope you post an answer about that, not just so I can upvote it but also because, although I've done my very best to write in such a way as to avoid giving this impression, I fear that--as long as mine is the only answer--a few less careful readers might think the method I've shown is necessary even when `readonly` is not used. My solution is a hackish curiosity; yours is a real solution that might be used even for reasons other than fun, and that transmits important knowledge about the effects of POSIX mode in Bash.

Comment: In `bash`, you can also do: `enable -n builtin unset command enable`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, that looks like another way to "hose" any possibility to access builtins.  (At a glance I thought it was a way to recover them.)  Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `bash` is in posix mode, some builtins are considered special, which is compliant with POSIX standard.

One special thing about those special builtins, they are found before function in command lookup process. Taking this advantage, you can try:

```
$ unset builtin
Haha, nice try!
builtin
$ set -o posix
$ unset builtin
$ builtin command -v echo
echo
```

though it does not work if `set` is overridden by a function named `set`:

```
$ set() { printf 'Haha, nice try!\n%s\n' "$*";}
$ set -o posix
Haha, nice try!
```

In this case, you just have to set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to make `bash` enter posix mode, then you have all special builtins:

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
```

Comment: ... you don't even need the export for that (also handling the case where export is masked)

Comment: @muru yes, copy-paste issue, fixed.

Answer (score 6):

> can you still recover if all three functions are marked readonly?

Yes, usually you can, though that does not mean you should.

Just as you can [unset readonly variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash) by attaching a debugger and calling `unbind_variable` as shown in [anishsane's answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17398009/1038860), you can also unset readonly functions passing their names to `unbind_func` using a debugger.

This is not a reasonable approach when they aren't readonly (if it indeed ever is). **In that situation you should use [cuonglm's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403852/11938), which takes advantage of how `unset` is treated in POSIX mode.** *That solution* is something you might actually use in real life.

Since there's no actual guarantee that your shell will behave reasonably after you circumvent `readonly` with a debugger, I suggest avoiding it whenever a more reasonable alternative, like quitting and restarting your shell or replacing your shell with a new one using `exec`, is available.

With that said, here's [anishsane's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17398009/1038860) adapted to unset functions instead of a variable:

```bash
cat <<EOF | sudo gdb
attach $$
call unbind_func("unset")
call unbind_func("builtin")
call unbind_func("command")
detach
EOF
```

Note that `$$` [is expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) into the shell's process ID, because no part of `EOF` in `<<EOF` is quoted.

I tested this on Bash 4.3.48(1)-release on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and it worked. You need `gdb` for this, though it could be adapted to other debuggers. As [anishsane commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash#comment39393335_17398009), piping from `cat` is intended to avoid a deadlock where the process that gives input to `gdb` is the one that `gdb` has stopped. I believe it achieves that goal, because in a pipeline of two or more commands, Bash runs each command in a subshell. But I am unsure if it is the most robust way. Ultimately, however, there's no actual guarantee that this works anyway, since it's entirely reasonable for Bash to assume readonly variables and functions won't change. In practice, my guess is that this does virtually always work.

To use this technique as written, you need `sudo` installed and you need to be able to `sudo` to root. You can, of course, replace it with another privilege-elevation method. Depending on what OS you are running and how it is configured, you might be able to omit `sudo` altogether and run `gdb` as yourself instead of root. For example, the Linux kernel will consult the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, which [you can set through sysctl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process) and may read or (as root) write, to determine what processes may debug other processes. If the value is `1`, then only a process's direct parent--or any process running as root--may debug it. Most recent GNU/Linux systems have it set to `1`, which is why I included `sudo`.

*That description of Linux kernel behavior is somewhat oversimplified, in that other `ptrace_scope` values are allowed and in that the relationship required by `1` can be adjusted. See [**the relevant documentation**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) for full details.*

Comment: Using `gdb` with only 1 `attach` directive could be passed as `gdb` argiumnent: `--pid`. See my [destroy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458406/1765658). (at same SO post you pointed out)

Comment: **[Avoid useless cat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/1765658)** !!! Use: `sudo gdb <<EOF ...`

Comment: That's already directly addressed in my answer: *"As [anishsane commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash#comment39393335_17398009), piping from `cat` is intended to avoid a deadlock where the process that gives input to `gdb` is the one that `gdb` has stopped."* (I think you may have seen that comment. But even if you've found the command you recommend to sometimes work, it is not obvious to me that it works as often. If you believe you have a solid analysis that it does, then I think that may make for a whole new answer, which could be of value.)